# Linux image update (linux-headers-4.15.0-106) made Ubuntu 18.04 LTS unbootable

Tags: boot, linux-headers

Recently there was an update on the Linux image update from Livepatch, and requires restart. But after restart, I cannot boot my Ubuntu at all. I do have 3 other images able to be used, but it somehow is a one-time use - I am stuck at the same loop

I inspected the /boot, and saw that the 3 images (initrd.img-4.15.0-101-generic, 106, 99) are somehow altered that it is unbootable. Here is the log on /boot. Has anyone encountered this problem? And is there any fixes to this problem?

```
samuraiwarm@samuraiwarm-ThinkPad-13:/boot$ ls -la
total 303380
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root     4096 Jun 10 18:23 .
drwxr-xr-x 29 root root     4096 Jun 10 17:02 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   217449 May 11 16:08 config-4.15.0-101-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   217473 Jun  4 17:16 config-4.15.0-106-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   217362 Sep 17  2019 config-4.15.0-65-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   217458 Apr 23 01:31 config-4.15.0-99-generic
drwx------  5 root root     4096 Jan  1  1970 efi
drwxr-xr-x  6 root root     4096 Jun 10 18:37 grub
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 64862602 Jun 10 17:03 initrd.img-4.15.0-101-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 64877796 Jun 10 17:03 initrd.img-4.15.0-106-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 64780759 May  7 16:38 initrd.img-4.15.0-65-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 64853590 Jun 10 18:23 initrd.img-4.15.0-99-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   182704 Jan 28  2016 memtest86+.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   184380 Jan 28  2016 memtest86+.elf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   184840 Jan 28  2016 memtest86+_multiboot.bin
-rw-------  1 root root  4072495 May 11 16:08 System.map-4.15.0-101-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  4073353 Jun  4 17:16 System.map-4.15.0-106-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  4064177 Sep 17  2019 System.map-4.15.0-65-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  4071696 Apr 23 01:31 System.map-4.15.0-99-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  8380064 May 11 16:14 vmlinuz-4.15.0-101-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  8380064 Jun  4 17:29 vmlinuz-4.15.0-106-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  8359576 Sep 17  2019 vmlinuz-4.15.0-65-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  8380056 Apr 23 01:32 vmlinuz-4.15.0-99-generic
```

Edit: here I submitted question in launchpad https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/691251

Update 11/7: It seems that version 65 can be bootable multiple times, but my Livepatch says error occurred when applying updates. I tried installing 3 more versions (96, 91, 64) just in case. Version 96 and 91 cannot be booted at all, but version 64 can.

Comment: "*cannot boot at all*" is vague. Seems like you can reach GRUB. What happens after that? Details are important - we cannot see what you are seeing. Take a video with your phone and post a link.

Comment: just for the record: I had the same problem. I've just updated my system to the image 4.15.0-106 and after boot screen, the system just gets stuck. I get the same if I select 4.15.0-101. I could only make it work when I selected 4.15.0-99. Since I need to work this afternoon, I'll just continue to use the system like that and won't restart the system for some time.

Comment: @user535733 My computer is a dual-boot with Windows and Ubuntu. Grub froze after selecting Ubuntu, works perfectly fine with Windows. I can choose alternative image from Advanced Ubuntu Options, but when I select the latest ver.106, it is stuck at "Loading Linux 4.15.0-106-generic, Loading initial ramdisk ...". And I wish I can take a video, but now I'm at the last Linux image, and I may not be able to use Ubuntu at all, so I have explained my best the description on what happened.

Comment: Please file a bug report against the `linux` package to let the developers know about the freeze-after GRUB issue. "*I'm at the last Linux image*" makes no sense since kernels are not single-use. You can reboot into an older working kernel as often as you wish. That's precisely why the system keeps at least one older kernel and why GRUB offers you the choice.

Comment: @user535733 _"kernels are not single-use"_ yes I expected them to be so, but it actually didn't. The image file could be corrupted after I reboot, as I have shown the `ls -la` on `/boot`, and shows that they are somehow changed at the time I reboot. Since I have seen others encountering the same problem, I will write a bug report now.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the problem by just remove and reinstall the headers. If you can still access Ubuntu with different Linux header, install other versions (like version 64) first, and back up all your documents first, just in case. My guess is that intel-microcode is updated a while after the unbootable problem. I was lucky that the version 65 can be booted multiple times.

```
sudo apt remove linux-headers-4.15.0-106-generic:amd64 linux-modules-4.15.0-106-generic:amd64 linux-image-4.15.0-106-generic:amd64 linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-106-generic:amd64 linux-headers-4.15.0-106:amd64
```

```
sudo apt install linux-headers-4.15.0-106-generic:amd64 linux-modules-4.15.0-106-generic:amd64 linux-image-4.15.0-106-generic:amd64 linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-106-generic:amd64 linux-headers-4.15.0-106:amd64
```